# Using ggplot2 as a function as a basemap to add rasters on

Tags: r, ggplot2, overlay, raster

I want to create a function where a basemap is created using ggplot. Then later I want this map to be used as the basemap to plot other spatial data on, mostly raster data.

I'm creating the basemap like this:

```
basemap <- function(){
return(ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf(size = 1, colour = "black") +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-10, 28), ylim = c(35, 70)) +
  xlab("Longitude") + ylab("Latitude") +
  annotation_scale(location = "br", width_hint = 0.3) +
  annotation_north_arrow(location = "tl", which_north = "true", 
                         pad_x = unit(0.1, "in"), pad_y = unit(0.1, "in"),
                         style = north_arrow_fancy_orienteering)
)
}
```

And using geom_raster I plot the values of a dataframe as a raster:

```
plot <- ggplot(ascplot, aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, fill = as.numeric(ascplot$"o3_col3(ppb)"))) +
  geom_raster() + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=rainbow(10)) +
  labs(fill = "O3 column ")
```

However, I have no idea how to make it possible to add these values on top of the basemap. I want to make a basemap because I'm going to plot a lot of rasters and this way is ensures the underlying info is the same.

I tried to create the basemap and then put it in a variable to later add the raster on, but this is not possible as it gives an error:

`Error: Don't know how to add plot to a plot`

Any advice on how to do this?

Below are what the basemap looks like, and below that an example of a raster I would like to overlay it on.

[image: Basemap] [image: Raster]

Comment: To guide you on your way, the first approach that comes to mind would be make sure the two different datasets have commensurate columns for latitude and longitude, and then you should be able to do something like `ggplot(data=world, aes(...)) +geom_sf(...) + geom_raster(aes(fill=), data=ascplot)` so you're 'adding geoms' rather than adding plots, but the data for the different geoms are coming from different sources.  You might then play around with transparency etc.

Comment: Hi Gavin, the lat/lon columns are both the same in min/max and value. I tried that method but then I get the "don't know how to add plot to plot" error message. Thanks.

Comment: Could you give a fully reproducible example, including the line that produces the error.  I can see why `plot1 + plot2` would produce that error, but not the `geom_sf + geom_raster` approach.